# Cycles - circular artefacts in displaced PBR render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, displacement, pbr

I'm trying to model a PBR leather material, with displacement modifier. The mesh is heavily subdivided to make the leather appear smooth and get the creases to have the correct shading.

However, when I'm rendering without anti-aliasing (`Cycles -> Film -> Filter=Gaussian, Width=0.01Px`), cycles is giving me really weird artefacts, ring-like shapes, see the image attached.

When anti-aliasing is turned on (Filter px width set to something like 1.5), these disappear. However, for my application, I must render without anti-aliasing.

Has anybody seen this before? I suspect it has to do with the displacement, as the texture is ray-marched until the displaced heightfield is intersected, but don't have any idea how to solve this. Any hints appreciated!

[image]

Edit: Guys, thanks for the help so far. I cannot share the blendfile, as it's too big for blendexchange due to the high number of vertices and the 4K texture maps. But I added the node-setup and another close-up. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might try changing the displacement pattern from 3D to 2D.

Comment: Well, when you disable anti-aliasing, you tend to get [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). The only thing I can think of to fix this is to lower your texture resolution until the texel size is ≥ the pixel size.

Comment: Does this look like a typical aliasing pattern to you? And even with anti-aliasing on, the effect is still there (less prominent, but still visible), it is just mitigated by the filtering... That's why I suspected there is something else going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Perhaps if you shared the node tree and some close-up renders (to mitigate the artifacts), I might spot something else at play here, but it just looks like aliasing to me. You can [edit] your question to include these.

Comment: Try to look into displacement and height map (if any) node setup. Make sure respectful images are set to non-color data, as well as nodes are connected correctly. You can provide your node setup as edit to the question

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Any ideas on this?